# Selecting a row by searching a specific value in an Array column

Tags: postgresql, elixir

We have a table where one of the columns is an array. I need to select a row or many rows as long as my search value matches their values using ILIKE. My problem is that I need to search the values of an array column as well. I tried using ANY but the value needs to be exact to select a row. I need something similar to ILIKE but for that array column.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`unnest`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) function:

```
SELECT x.value
FROM my_table t, unnest(t.my_array_column) as x(value)
WHERE x.value ILIKE 'foo'
```

Once your question is also tagged [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir), for converting this to *Ecto* use [`Ecto.Query.API.fragment/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#fragment/1) for the select condition and [`Ecto.Query.API.ilike/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html?#ilike/2) for match.

Comment: Except that you cannot reference the alias value in the where clause directly. Either the `unnest` should be in `from` clause or use `where` outside a subquery. 1st one is the preferred option.

Comment: @KaushikNayak oh, indeed, thank you. I did not tackle with [tag:postgresql] for a long while :(